# Is there a way in c++11 to prevent "normal" operations from sliping before or after atomic operation

Tags: multithreading, atomic, c++11

I'm interested in doing something like(single thread update, multiple threads read banneedURLs):

```cpp
atomic<bannedURLList*> bannedURLs;//global variable pointing to the currently used instance of struct
void  updateList()
{
       //no need for mutex because only 1 thread updates
       bannedURLList* newList= new bannedURLList();
       bannedURLList* oldList=bannedURLs;
       newList->initialize();
       bannedURLs=newList;// line must be after previous line, because list must be initialized before it is ready to be used

      //while refcnt on the oldList >0 wait, then delete oldList;
}
```

reader threads do something like this:

```cpp
{
   bannedURLs->refCnt++;
   //use bannedURLs
   bannedURLs->refCnt--;
}
```

struct memeber refCnt is also atomic integer
My question is how to prevent reordering of this 2 lines:

```cpp
newList->initialize();
bannedURLs=newList;
```

Can it be done in std:: way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bannedURLs.store(newList);` instead of `bannedURLs=newList;`. Since you didn't pass a weak ordering specifier, this forces full ordering in the store.

Comment: I'm surprised you can even assign directly like that - I thought you *always* have to use `store()` for atomics.